# C# - How to use Reflection to invoke static method with variable number of parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, reflection

I want to identify the following method via reflection:

```
String.Concat(params string[] args);
```

This is what I have tried:

```
MethodInfo concatMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new Type[] { typeof(string[]) });
```

The method is being identified correctly, but when I try to invoke it:

```
object concatResult = concatMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { "A", "B" });
```

I get the following exception:

```
TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
```

Also note that I am passing `null` as the instance argument to the `Invoke` method, this is because the method is static and therefore an instance is not needed. Is this approach correct?

**PS**: I want to simulate the following call:

```
String.Concat("A", "B");
```

Comment: Try use `new object[] { new string[] { "A", "B" } }` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each element of the input array is a parameter to the method. The overload of `Concat` you have takes a single `string[]` argument so you need:

```
object concatResult = concatMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { new string[] { "A", "B" } });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, worked as expected. I'll mark as correct answer as soon as I'm able